# How to achieve isolation in mongodb 4.0?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I'm new to Mongodb.
I'd like to understand if it's possible or not to achieve full isolation for reads and updates.
For example, I have the following flow:

1. Count documents from a collection based on some filter.
2. Based on the result, update another document.

So basically I want to understand how to prevent a concurrent write operation to enter between 1 & 2 .

BTW I'm using the java driver 3.12

Thanks
Shira

Comment: check this https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/

Comment: Thanks @Sohan but this page actually says that transactions and causal consistent sessions do not guarantee isolation.

Answer (score 0):

Latest versions of mongoDB has transactions features, maybe you can check that.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/

Comment: Transactions alone seem to not provide "serializable" isolation level if I understand correctly. And this level of isolation is what I need in some use cases.